# Probability of getting a strictly larger number each time

Tags: probability, probability-theory

> Choose a four-digit number at random. What is the probability that four digits are in strictly increasing order? (Note that the first place can't be a zero)

**Edit:**

What I've done:

Let $A_k$: Getting a strictly increasing number starting with $1$

$$P(A_1)= \left[\frac{1}{9} \cdot \frac{1}{10} \cdot \frac{1}{10} \left(\frac{6}{10} + \frac{5}{10} +\cdots+ \frac{1}{10} \right)\right]+\left[ \frac{1}{9} \cdot\frac{1}{10} \cdot \frac{1}{10} \left(\frac{5}{10} + \frac{4}{10} +\cdots+ \frac{1}{10}\right)\right]+\cdots+\left[\frac{1}{9} \cdot \frac{1}{10} \cdot \frac{1}{10}\left(\frac{1}{10}\right)\right]  =  \frac{6\cdot7+5\cdot6+\cdots+1\cdot2}{2\cdot9\cdot10^3} $$

Similarly I calculated $P(A_k)$ for $k=2,3\cdots6$ and then added all these up.

Is this correct?

Comment: Hint; how many ways can you pick 4 digits from 0 to 9 (with an order) ? Okay, well not all of these configurations are candidates for being in [strictly] increasing order, you need that the 4 digits be distinct-- how many ways can you do that? And how many ways can the 4 digits be distinct and the first not be zero? Great! One example of such a candidate number is 1432, for each such candidate there are [blank] orderings of the digits, [blank] of them is/are in strictly increasing order. Can you take it from here? Next time it helps to say what you've tried/have been thinking.

Comment: @mb- I've added what I've tried. Please let me know if it is correct.

Comment: I don't see how $P(A_1)$ equals $\frac{1}{9} * \frac{1}{10} * \frac{1}{10} [\frac{6}{10} + \frac{5}{10} +...+ \frac{1}{10}]$, and I certainly don't see how $\frac{1}{9} * \frac{1}{10} * \frac{1}{10} [\frac{6}{10} + \frac{5}{10} +...+ \frac{1}{10}]$ equals $\frac{6.7+5.6+...+1.2}{2.9.10^3}$.

Comment: I'm sorry I typed it wrong. I have corrected my mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are $9999-999=9000$ four digit numbers, all equiprobable. A good number has four different digits in ascending order, the first  being $\geq1$. We can select these digits in ${9\choose 4}=126$ ways; thereupon the good number is determined, since the digits have to appear in increasing order. It follows that the probability in question amounts to
$${126\over9000}={7\over500}=0.014\ .$$

Answer (score 1):

Not only can the first place not be 0.  No place can be 0.

Strictly increasing order $\implies$  No digits are the same.

Before addressing increasing order, how many numbers fit this criteria?

1 permutation of the digits puts it in increasing order.

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Can you please check my solution?

Comment: @SahibaArora  # 4 digit numbers with digits in increasing order / # 4 digit numbers.  $\frac {9\choose 4}{9000}$